# How to have multiple y axis on a line graph in Python

Tags: python, graph

I want to make a line graph with multiple sets of data on the same graph. But they all scale differently so will need individual y axis scales.

What code will put each variable on a separate axis?

Comment: 1. What frameworks/modules are you using?  2. What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is to write a method that allows you to scale the y value for each data set to lay on the graph the way you want it.  Then all your data points will have a y value on the same scale, and you can label the Y axis based upon how you define your translation for each data set.